# PWA iOS getting the sms: tag to open iMessage

Tags: ios, sms, progressive-web-apps

We are currently developing a PWA for a client of ours.  Everything has been going well, but while testing on iPhone (iOS 12.2) we are having an issue with the  tags that have sms:123-456-7890 in the href.  You get the "Safari cannot open this page because of the sms: tag" (paraphrasing).

If you are browsing the site via Safari (not in the PWA mode), the anchor tag works fine and your iMessage opens up with the number in it.  But when you're in the PWA mode and click the link, you get a version of the message I mentioned above.

From doing research, this appears to be some sort of bug in the iOS 12.2 release, though not officially mentioned.

I'm curious if anyone has had any luck with a work-around for this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Edit..to add some code for the anchor tag....

```
<a href="sms://1234567890;">123-456-7890</a>
```

I've tried many different variations of the sms (with no // or ;), always same outcome when clicking it as a PWA.  With Android, everything works fine in PWA mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did find a workaround by using JavaScript

Code Example:

```
<a href="#" onclick="openSMSMobile();" >

function openSMSMobile(e) {           
        window.open('sms:1234567890', '_self');
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And in case anyone is wondering, if you'd like to add text to the message body, you can use,

```
window.open('sms:1234567890&body=textGoesHere', '_self');
```

For Android you'll need,

```
window.open('sms:1234567890&body=textGoesHere', '_self');
```